# throw error message is not getting caught by the catch method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm following a react tutorial about handling fetch errors on YouTube. I did exactly what the instructor did but for some reason the catch method is not catching the throw error message. Here's the code:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState(null);
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      fetch("http://localhost:8000/blogs")
        .then((res) => {
          if (!res.ok) {
            throw Error("This error is not getting caught");
          }
          return res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          setBlogs(data);
          setIsPending(false);
          setError(null);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setIsPending(false);
          setError(err.message);
        });
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="home">
      {error && <div>{error} </div>}
      {isPending && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {blogs && <BlogList blogs={blogs} title="All Blogs!" />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Note: the server is not running.

Comment: What the error you are getting ?

Comment: It just shows the default error message, "Failed to fetch", instead of my error message "This error is not getting caught".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first `.then` from `fetch` will be entered into *when the response headers are received*. The response headers may indicate that there's a problem - if the response isn't `.ok` - in which case your `throw Error` will be entered into as desired and send control flow down to the lower `.catch`.

But if no response headers are received at all, the first `.then` will *not* be entered into - instead, a network error will cause a rejection and the `.catch` below will be entered into directly.

Your code results in `Failed to fetch` being displayed, since that's the error message from a failed request that doesn't even get any headers back:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const Home = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState(null);
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      fetch("http://localhost:8000/blogs")
        .then((res) => {
          if (!res.ok) {
            throw Error("This error is not getting caught");
          }
          return res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          setBlogs(data);
          setIsPending(false);
          setError(null);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setIsPending(false);
          setError(err.message);
        });
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="home">
      {error && <div>{error} </div>}
      {isPending && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {blogs && <BlogList blogs={blogs} title="All Blogs!" />}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

If you wanted to have `This error is not getting caught` displayed in this sort of situation too, change

```
setError(err.message);
```

to

```
setError('This error is not getting caught');
```